# Divs with vw are overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have for days tried to solve a problem with two divs overlapping without any luck. I want the .kolonneWrapper to be underneath .shrink-wrap, instead the .shrink-wrap dissappears under .kolonneWrapper like this [subheader disappears.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN4X4.jpg) How can I correct this? https://jsfiddle.net/s2wmLjhq/

```css
html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
}
.totalWrapper{
  width: 964px;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50%;
}
.shrink-wrap{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  top: -10%;
  margin: -15px 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  display: flex;
}
.subSubHeaderImage{ 
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right:-50vw;
  background: url(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-
  content/uploads/2017/04/sandwichmaaler.png) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;   
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible; 
}
.kolonneWrapper{
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px auto -30px auto
  background-position: center;
  background: #fff;
  background size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -ms-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 50px 0;
  position: absolute; 
}
.wrapperImidten{
  width: 964px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> 
  <div class="shrink-wrap">
    <div class="subSubHeaderImage"></div>
  </div> <!--end of .shrink-wrap-->

  <div class="kolonneWrapper">
    <div class="wrapperImidten">
    </div> <!--end of .wrapperImidten-->
  </div> <!--end of .kolonneWrapper-->

</div> <!--end of .wrapper-->
```

Comment: share your actual code in like jsfiddle or codepen, so that you can get the accurate solution

Comment: I can tell you that the `vw` unit in this case is likely unrelated. The height's looks fishy, remember that it is 100% height of parent element, but you have no set height anywhere.  You are using `totalWrapper` in your css, but `wrapper` in your html. Also a missing dash in `background-size`, (but I'm guessing the browser skips past that line). And the jsfiddle doesn't seem to match the picture. Maybe you could provide more context (like the actual problem you are facing). At this point it's hard to figure out what you have. (Also I think the z-index suggestion is nonsense)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)you must assign `Height` for `.shrink-wrap`**

For Example :

```
.shrink-wrap{

  height: 500px;

}
```

**2)If you want use `height:100%` must assign parent's height (.wrapper) :**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;

}
```

and use `height:100%` :

```
.shrink-wrap{
  width: 100vw;
  height:100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}
```

**3) Or use `vw` unit Like this :**

```
.shrink-wrap{

  height:100vw;

  //More codes

}
```

Comment: The height needs to be responsive, that is why it is set to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give them z-index with all your codes add this sets of lines

```
.subSubHeaderImage{
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
```

and

```
.kolonneWrapper{
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
}
```

> this is just a guide you should play more with the z-index to stack
>   your content you can check out this [Mozilla Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index?v=example)